# Can I add a specific image from a selected radio button to a Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple single choice question as radio buttons with text and image. When a button has been selected and Submit button pressed a pop up will appear stating which Image has been selected but I would like to add the selected image to popup as well. I assuming I cannot add a specific image to the radio button value? Code shown below.. any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
function sending(a)
{
window.location.href='b.html#id='+a.id+'&src='+a.src;
}


function myFunction() {
var radios = document.getElementsByName('ImageSelected');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            // do whatever you want with the checked radio
            //alert(radios[i].value);
        alert("You Selected - " + radios[i].value);
            // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
            break;
        }
}
```

}

```
<div class="">

<form action="#n" name="theForm">

<label for="gender">Please Select Correct Image: </label><br><br>

<input type="radio" name="ImageSelected" value="Image 1" id="Image 1">
<label for="image01">Image 1<br><img src="image01.jpg"><br></label><br>

<input type="radio" name="ImageSelected" value="Image 2" id="Image 2">
<label for="image02">Image 2<br><img src="image02.jpg"><br></label><br>

<input type="radio" name="ImageSelected" value="Image 3" id="Image 3">
<label for="image03">Image 3<br><img src="image03.jpg"><br></label><br><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

</form>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

Popup Should display selected Text and image if possible?

Comment: JavaScript native popups (i.e, through `window.alert`) cannot display images.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by crating image place holder on `Modal` and add `src` attributes
 on this `img` here is how

```js
function myFunction() {
      var imgPath = document.mainForm.ImageSelected.value;
           document.getElementById("myModal").className += "show";
           document.getElementById("myModal").className -= "hide";
            document.getElementById("myModal").setAttribute('src',imgPath)
            console.log(imgPath);
}
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}

.show {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
  
  
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="" id="img"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>




<div class="">

<form name="mainForm">
<label for="gender">Please Select Correct Image: </label><br><br>

<input type="radio" name="ImageSelected" value="Image 1" id="Image 1">
<label for="image01">Image 1<br><img src="image01.jpg"><br></label><br>

<input type="radio" name="ImageSelected" value="Image 2" id="Image 2">
<label for="image02">Image 2<br><img src="image02.jpg"><br></label><br>

<input type="radio" name="ImageSelected" value="Image 3" id="Image 3">
<label for="image03">Image 3<br><img src="image03.jpg"><br></label><br><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
</form>


<p id="demo"></p>
```